# Value_counts() on array of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have array = ['T4U measured','FTI measured', 'lithium'] and need to do value_counts on all these columns.

something like df[array].value_counts(), which show histogram of values in columns

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have a question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show (code!) what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DataFrame.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) method:

```
for i in range(0, len(array)):
    df[array[i]].hist(bins=df[array[i]].value_counts())
```

This method works on the whole dataframe, in case you don't want to call it on each column separately. But in that case, you cannot adjust the number of bins to each column.